# Error when create multiple ACI via Azure ARM template using COPY

Tags: azure, azure-devops, copy, azure-rm-template, azure-container-instances

I am currently trying to deploy a container group inside Azure Container Instances via ARM template all called from Azure Devops Yaml build pipeline. I have found out that I can use *copy* sentence to create multiple Resource Groups and/or properties.

Here is my ARM template

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "containerGroupName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Emulators ACR name."
        }
    },
    "copies":{
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 2,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the number of container's copies."
        }
    },
    "server":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACR server url."
        }
    },
    "serverUser":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACR user."
        }
    },
    "serverPassword":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACR password."
        }
    },
    "imageName":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACR repository hosting the image."
        }
    },
    "imageVersion":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACR image version."
        }
    },
    "containerName":{
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Defines the ACI containers name. This will be suffixed with the copy index."
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "emulatorImage": "[concat(parameters('server'), '/', parameters('imageName'))]",
    "emulatorImageVersion": "[parameters('imageVersion')]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('containerGroupName'), '-', copyIndex(1))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "acicopy",
            "count": "[if(equals(mod(parameters('copies'), 60), 0), div(parameters('copies'), 60), add(div(parameters('copies'), 60), 1))]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "containers",
                    "count": "[if(equals(div(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60), 0), if(equals(mod(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60), 0), 60, mod(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60)), 0)]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('containerName'), '-', copyIndex(1), copyIndex('containers', 1))]",
                        "properties": {
                            "image": "[concat(variables('emulatorImage'), ':' ,variables('emulatorImageVersion'))]",
                            "resources": {
                                "requests": {
                                    "cpu": 0.01,
                                    "memoryInGB": 0.1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "imageRegistryCredentials": [
                {
                    "server": "[parameters('server')]",
                    "username": "[parameters('serverUser')]",
                    "password": "[parameters('serverPassword')]"
                }
            ],
            "osType": "Linux"
        }
    }
]
```

}

As you can see I have two *copy* iterations. The first one on the RG to generate enough Container Instances (as I am limited to 60 containers per ACI) and the second one on properties, to generate multiple containers (max 60).

So, if I need 100 containers, I should create 2 ACI, the first one will contain 60 containers the second one 40.

The conditions on count properties of *copy* might look a little complicated to read, so here is the C# equivalence.

```
public static void DefineNumber(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number : " + number);
    int mainLoop = number % 60 == 0 ? (int)(number / 60) : (int)(number / 60) + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("MainLoop : " + mainLoop);

    for(int i = 0; i < mainLoop; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----");

        int div = (number - (60 * i)) / 60;
        Console.WriteLine("Div : " + div);

        int mod = (number - (60 * i)) % 60;
        Console.WriteLine("Mod : " + mod);  

        int iteration = div == 0 ? (mod == 0 ? 60 : mod) : 60;
        Console.WriteLine("Number of containers for main loop n°" + (i+1) + " will be : " + iteration);
    }
}
```

**mainloop** is for the first *copy* iteration

**iteration** is for the second one

The problem I am currently facing is that when I ask the template to create 100 containers, I have the following build error

[image]

The message is clear enough, but I don't understand where the problem is. **imageRegistryCredentials** property is defined once for each *copy* iteration, and located on the same level as the *containers* property, so why do it succeed on first iteration, then fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was going wrong in my ARM template. It was a stupid mistyping error .... In my "properties" copy iteration functions at the end I have put a 0 value instead of 60

```
"count": "[if(equals(div(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60), 0), if(equals(mod(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60), 0), 60, mod(sub(parameters('copies'), mul(60, copyIndex())), 60)), 0)]",
```

If I replace it by C# equivalence,

**What I should have put:**

```
 int iteration = div == 0 ? (mod == 0 ? 60 : mod) : 60;
```

**What I put:**

```
 int iteration = div == 0 ? (mod == 0 ? 60 : mod) : 0;
```

The difference is at the end...

Anyway thank you [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) for your help !

Comment: Done :) I had to wait 2 days before being able to accept my own answer

Answer (score 0):

According to what I know ( I didnt revisit this particular scenario in a very long time ) - you cannot use copy and properties copy on the same resource. your workaround would be - create linked deployments (1 for each 60 containers) and then you would only need properties copy inside each of those.

but given this error, I'm not sure that this scenario is not possible at this point in time. Because previously it would complain about copyIndex() not being expected at that place.

Comment: Well, actually, when I set the number of copies to 60 this works perfectly, It creates one instance of 60 containers.and as you may see, there is two different copyIndexes, one for resource (without the naming) and the second one for the properties (which requires a name inside copy props). So the first copy value is 1 and the second is 60. But if first iteration should happen more than once it fires this error ...

Comment: Another interesting detail. If I replace the copy count with hardcoded values, everything works great ! I have tryied with 2 iterations of 60 containers, and it worked.. I will check the way I calculate the count.

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to debug the ARM functions but the only problem that may happen (I don't know how yet) is that the "mainLoop"(first copy iteration) returns the value+1. Ex: if I want 100 containes the mainLoop value should be equal to 2, but somehow it is equal to 3. However when I loop on properties "copy" when I enter the third "mainLoop" iteration I try to create 0 containers. So my container property is empty but my "imageRegistryCredentials" property is populated. But I have no Idea why this would happen, as the division in ARM returns the lowest *int* value => 8 / 3 = 2